# how to find return minimal values in each column in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I have a dataframe looks like:

```
a  b  c  d
2  4  2  7
4  2  3  8
5  3  2  9
```

I want to return 2 2 2 7.

I would like if there is a function to do this, or the most efficient to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`df.min(axis=0)`

Axis keyword changes between rows or columns.